# How to handle selected data from LEFT JOIN query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I want to execute a query that selects *all* customers, and the corresponding addresses for each customer. Every customer can have zero, one, or multiple addresses.

This is something I tried:

```
sql = "SELECT customers.*, addresses.* FROM customers LEFT JOIN addresses ON addresses.CustomerId = customers.Id ORDER BY customers.Id OFFSET @start ROWS FETCH NEXT @end ROWS ONLY";

List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@start", limitStart));
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@end", limitEnd));
DataSet set = Db.ExecuteSelectQuery(sql, parameters);


DataTable table = set.Tables["customers"];

Console.WriteLine("Tables count: " + set.Tables.Count); // says there's 1 table.

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.Id = row.Field<int>("Id");
    cust.ClientNumber = row.Field<string>("clientnumber");
    cust.Date = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("date"));
    cust.Firstname = row.Field<string>("firstname");
    cust.Insertion = row.Field<string>("insertion");
    cust.Lastname = row.Field<string>("lastname");

    foreach(DataRow addrRow in /* ......?...... */) // Want to loop through addresses of the current customer row.
    {
        Address address = new Address();
        address.Street = addrRow.Field<string>("Street");
        address.HouseNumber = addrRow.Field<string>("Number");
        address.PostalCode = addrRow.Field<string>("PostalCode");
        address.City = addrRow.Field<string>("City");
        address.Country = 0;// row.Field<int>("CountryCode");

        cust.Addresses.Add(address);
    }

    customers.Add(cust);
}

return customers;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to process the query result using the `DataTable`, and `DataSet` classes of `SqlClient`.

I can't find anything on the internet explaining the way you can access the selected addresses for each customer.

Can someone explain me, or perhaps show me a code sample?

Comment: It may help. Have you defined relation between the two tables ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbt8xha8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When I tried to add a `DataRelation`, the relation asks for two `DataColumns` in its constructor. To access the columns, I tried using `set.Tables` to get a Table, and get the column from that table object. But one of the problems is that the set contains only one table. (See the Console write of my code).

Comment: `Db.ExecuteSelectQuery` with this query just get result in one table that each row has fields of both tables customers and addresses, in your loop check if customerId is different from previous one add new customer to list and check another like this for address list

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the addresses that belong to the customer which is the current customer in loop

You can even use an `if` clause to compare `cust.Id` with `row.Field<int>("CustomerId")`

Comment: Actually in your development, you have two data tables. But your SELECT query will produce only one table. If there are not multiple addresses for a customer, then you can use your query and change the .NET code by using address fields from "row" object. If there is not an address for the customer, the "row" fields related with address will be NULL .  If there are multiple addresses for a customer, then your SELECT statement will dublicate customer data too for each address of that customer.

Comment: Additionally, instead of using "*" for all, simply add field names like customer.id, address.id as addressid, etc. If there are fields on two tables with the same name, those will cause problems during query execution

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use linq library in the second for each

```
 foreach(DataRow addrRow in /* ......?...... */) // Want to loop through addresses of the current customer row.
{
```

Like so :

```
foreach(DataRow addrRow in table.Rows.Where(x=>x.Field<int>("Id")==cust.Id)) // Want to loop through addresses of the current customer row.
{
```

Your code will still generate duplicate customer entries in your customer list so maybe add a condition at the top of the first foreach loop:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  if(customers.Where(x=>x.Id == row.Field<int>("Id").Any())continue;
```